# How to save array in another array?

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop, telegram-bot

In a for loop, I have an array of array and I want to save all indexes to another array. How can I do that?

Here is my code:

```
//var : 
$saves =array();
$saves_id =array(); 
$saveus = array(); 

$result  = $conn->query("SELECT performer,file_id,title FROM databasebot 
WHERE performer = '$message' or title = '$message'");

while ($row=mysqli_fetch_row($result))
{
    // array title
    $saves[] = $row[2];
    // array file_id
    $saves_id[] = $row[1];    
}
$arrlength = count($saves);

for($x = 0; $x <= $arrlength; $x++) {          
    $poets['keyboard'][] = array($saves[$x]);    
    $jsonPoets= json_encode($poets);
    $text= "choose a song : ";
    // send message ... !
    $url= "https://api.telegram.org/bot".$token."/sendMessage?
    chat_id=".$chat_id."&text=".$text."&reply_markup=".$jsonPoets;
    file_get_contents($url);
}
```

In the for loop, I want to use the send message method (telegram bot) a few times (`$arrlength`) with just one-time text(not a few times, always 1 time). For example, this for loop will maybe repeat 20 times and I want to send a message 20 times and 1-time text, but my code is sending a message with text more than once! I think I should move my send message method from the for loop and save all indexes array in another array.

For example, this for loop repeats 3 times and I want to save all 3 indexes in another array.

Comment: `$saveus[$x] = $poets[$x] +$saveus[$x];` need to be `$saveus[$x][] = $poets[$x] +$saveus[$x];`. You are overwriting your same index again and again

Comment: Btw please add input values of `$saves,$poets ,$arrlength` to clarify your question. It's completely unclear what you are trying to do.Also add your expected outcome what you want from input values

Comment: edited , is it clear now ?

Answer (score 0):

User `array_keys` to store all the array keys in other array

```
<?php
$array = array(0 => 100, "color" => "red");
$poets['keyboard'][] = array_keys($array);
```